# User Profile page - one user can only access one page

Tags: users, user-profile, current-user

I'm new to craft, in fact I haven't built a site with it yet, but am looking forward to getting my teeth into this interesting and seemingly very flexible CMS.

I am about to embark on a medium sized website build and have a question that is kind of a deal breaker for choosing the CMS. My question is:

Can I create users that have their own profile page, who can only edit their own page and do nothing else? This won't be a public registration, but administered internally, however they must be able to maintain a profile containing images, text and predetermined layouts that they can choose between.

Thanks guys!

---

Brad, 
Thanks so much for your response.

Regarding the URL - could it be configured to be something like mydomain.com/members/membername instead of passing a url option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely.

From the template side you'd do something like this to ensure they're editing their own page:

```
{# assuming the URL structure for the profile page looks something like http://mydomain.com/users?id=5 %}

{% set editUserId = craft.request.getParam('id') %}

{% if editUserId and currentUser.id == editUserId %}
    You're in!
{$ else %}
    {% exit 403 %}
{% endif %}
```

Where [currentUser](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/global-variables#currentUser) is a global variable that's a [UserModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/usermodel) object.

Comment: Brad, Thanks so much for your response.

Regarding the URL - could it be configured to be something like mydomain.com/members/membername instead of passing a url option?

Comment: Sure, but that's still passing it through the URL.  You're just using their username instead of their ID.

Comment: Finally, can I allow one user enter the CP and only edit their own profile there, or does it have to be administered by them on the front end?

Comment: I can say, that coming to the end of this project, the user admin / front end templating has been nothing short of incredible. With such a helpful community both here on stackexchange and slack, I feel that I can achieve almost anything with craft!